# Disabling orientation change animations in phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

In my main javascript file I am detecting orientation changes from phonegap using *shouldRotateToOrientation(rotation)* to control css transitions of my content. How can I disable IOS's default rotation animations on orientation change?

I am using phonegap 1.1.0, xcode 4.2.1, targeting ios 4.3. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I ended up disabling all animations with `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];` inside the `webViewDidFinishLoad` function of AppDelegate.m.